# 75 ohm cable in an otherwise 50 ohm antenna system: Can I impedance match it?

Tags: rf, analog, antenna, impedance-matching

I have an marine radio antenna installation as shown in the diagram. Can I place baluns (or similar devices) at either end of the 75 Ω cable to solve the impedance mismatch problem?

[image]

**Background**

In case you can't see the image, it's a 50 Ω VHF radio (156-174 MHz) connected to 10 feet of 75 Ω coax cable, connected to a 50 Ω SO-239 bulkhead connector, connected to 33 feet of 50 Ω RG-58U cable, connected to a 50 Ω antenna. I believe the antenna is a half-wave dipole but I'm not certain about that.

This is an analog radio but it also uses digital services (marine Digital Selective Calling). GPS reception is by a separate antenna.

Unfortunately, the 75 Ω cable can't realistically be replaced because it's run inside the hull in a way that makes it impossible to swap out. It could be by-passed but the main point of this post is to find a way to avoid that. Also, replacing the radio isn't realistically an option, either.

Is this impedance mismatch even enough to worry about? Using an online calculator I came up with 8 percent total loss but I'm not at all confident that I used the right calculation. Since the radio is a safety device it's important that it work well but I might not be too concerned about only a few percent loss in transmit or receive performance.

Comment: You won't be feeding a half-wave dipole on coax unless there is also a balun at the antenna. Is the radio a transceiver? What power output?

Comment: Sorry, should have though to mention that. The radio is a transceiver that transmits at either 1 W or 25 W.

Comment: A "balun" is a "balanced - unbalanced" adapter.  If you only have co-ax, you should probably just remove that word from your question.  If you have two-wire antenna cable instead of coax, you should make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

An LC impedance matching network might suit your purpose for the unbalanced parts of your system (Everything but the antenna).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fujZW2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For reference, I used [this calculator](https://leleivre.com/rf_lcmatch.html) to obtain the values used in this circuit. The circuit is tuned for 165 MHz. At other nearby frequencies, the matching will be slightly off. You could probably use a 27 pF capacitor and a 100 nH inductor, which are standard sizes, and still get fairly decent results.

Further, you can probably find a matching network for those impedances at that frequency band pre-built, including the connector, available commercially.

<s>Your antenna probably already has a balun. But if not, you will need a balun to connect the 50 \$\Omega\$ cable to the antenna.</s>

Per a note by Peter Bennett

> Marine VHF antennas are designed to be fed by 50 Ohm coax - no balun or matching network needed at the antenna.

---

Edit:

> The radio is a transceiver that transmits at either 1 W or 25 W.

It probably goes without saying, but the circuit components need to be adequately rated for the current through the 75 \$\Omega\$ cable. Due to the possibility of standing waves, you will want something a bit higher than

$$I = \sqrt{\frac{P}{R}} = \sqrt{\frac{25}{50}} = 707 \text{mA}$$

1 A is a reasonable choice, or even more for safety.

> Where would I look for something like that?

Unfortunately, questions like that are discouraged here. We call them "shopping questions". However, I did do a search, and was somewhat surprised. I didn't find an off the shelf device that does what you are looking for. It is surprising because I don't imagine you are the first person to want to connect a 75 ohm cable in a 50 ohm system in the marine band. Be that as it may, if you search with terms like "impedance matching", you will find "L-pads" for sale. These are NOT what you want. They do match impedance, but at the cost of attenuating your signal. That's useful for some applications, but not if you want the strongest radio signal. So, it looks like you may have to make your own. I can't say whether or not it is worth it. Impedance mismatch will cause reflections in your system, which may adversely affect your transmitted power. Or not.

Comment: Marine VHF antennas are designed to be fed by 50 Ohm coax - no balun or matching network needed at the antenna.

Comment: "...you can probably find a matching network for those impedances..."

Where would I look for something like that? I tried DigiKey but, other than balun, I didn't know what to search for.